# How to testing preFlush event in doctrine

Tags: events, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I have a event preFlush:

```
/**
 * On flush event
 *
 * @param PreFlushEventArgs $event
 */
public function preFlush(PreFlushEventArgs $event)
{
   $em = $event->getEntityManager();
   $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

   foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
       if ($entity instanceof Answer) {
           // Set last answered
           $question = $entity->getQuestion();
           $question->setChanged(new \DateTime('now'));
           $uow->persist($question);
       }
   }
}
```

I want check set questions to uow.
Try create mock UnitOfWork, method - persist, but this is not work, because answer object not set to "UOW:entityInsertions".

Comment: Could be a bit clearer on your question? And elaborate more about what you actually tried... Posting your code should help too.

Comment: why you don't use "prePersist" event with your Question entity directly to update your "changed" value after data is modified? If you do so, then you don't need mock unit of work. Look here for more info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks